# Extracting data from one sheet based on a cell value into a new sheet using VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm currently attempting to create an automated action plan sheet for a quality report in Excel.
The source sheet is an expanded version of the table in the image below and lists a score for each sub reference within a larger 'area of enquiry':

[Image of the source table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fe3KP.png)

I'm trying to write a script that will loop through Column C in the source sheet, and where the score is either -5 or 0, I want to extract the reference from Column B and place it in the next available row in the first column of a sheet called 'Action Plan'. So using the above table as an example, I'd expect the action plan table to resemble the table below:

[Expected results in the Action Plan sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5aGU.png)

I currently have the script below, but although I don't get any errors, nothing seems to be happening other than jumping to the first row in Column C of the source sheet.

```
Sub newloop()

Dim lRow As Integer
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim FRow As Integer
Dim domainws As Worksheet
Dim apws As Worksheet

Set domainws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Safe")
Set apws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Action Plan")

lastrow = apws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
lRow = domainws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

domainws.Activate

For FRow = 3 To lRow
    If domainws.Cells(FRow, 22) = "0" Then
        apws.Cells(lastrow, 2).Value = domainws.Cells(FRow, 2)
    ElseIf domainws.Cells(FRow, 22) = "-5" Then
        apws.Cells(lastrow, 2).Value = domainws.Cells(FRow, 2)
    End If
Next FRow

End Sub
```

As a bonus, I do have five different source sheets that I also need to loop through (all the data is in the same place, they just have different row counts) so ideally would like this all to happen within the same loop, but I could also just duplicate and adapt the loop for the other four sheets if needed.

Very grateful for any guidance that can be given.

Comment: You should change `lrow`,`lastrow` and `FRow` to `Long` instead of `Integer`.  If you have more than 32,767 rows it cannot handle them.

Comment: What are the values of `lastrow` and `lRow`? Also note that with `apws.Cells(lastrow, 2).Value` you always write into the exact same cell since `lastrow` doesn't change in your loop. So probably `lastrow = apws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1` needs to be within your loop.

Comment: Finally if you have real numbers in your cells you should check for real numbers by changing `= "0"` into `= 0` and `= "-5"` into `= -5` otherwise you are checking for strings (text). • If all this does not help, debug your code using F8 to go through the code step by step and checking the variable values.

Answer (score 0):

This should resolve your issues:

```
Sub newloop()

Dim lRow As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim FRow As Long
Dim domainws As Worksheet
Dim apws As Worksheet

Set apws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Action Plan")

For Each domainws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If domainws.Name <> "Action Plan" Then
        lRow = domainws.Cells(domainws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        For FRow = 3 To lRow
            lastrow = apws.Cells(apws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            If domainws.Cells(FRow, 22) = 0 Or _
               domainws.Cells(FRow, 22) = -5 Then
                apws.Cells(lastrow, 2).Value = domainws.Cells(FRow, 2)
            End If
        Next FRow
    End If
Next domainws
End Sub
```

This is based on the assumption that the only sheet you don't want to read is the `Action Plan` sheet. If there are others, you could expand the `If domainws.Name <>...` line to exclude others, or you could instead write the loop to only read certain sheets.

Also, although your screengrab is suggesting the 3 columns are together, the code suggests otherwise as you are checking if column V (column 22 - Score) contains 0 or -5 but then copying the value of column B (column 2 - Ref) *- is that intentional? - if not, change the 22 to the correct column number, such as 3?)*